# Problem with internet connection Alfa AWUS036H on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, alfa-wireless

i installed Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 today. And i am having a problem with my internet connection. Here is the situation, i am using an Alfa AWUS036H as my network adapter and when i connect to a wireless network it works only for a few seconds, and then the download rate becomes very slow and after a few seconds more it becomes zero. But the signal strength is always 3/4. Tried to disable IPv6 and it didn't help. I am new to Linux and ubuntu so i would be very happy if someone could help me.

Comment: I partially fixed it. I uninstalled network-manager and now i am using Wicd instead. The slow speed is gone now but it continues to disconnect after some short time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Zyxel Adapter. After a few days trying to solve the issue without success, I bought a new adapter compatible "out-of-the-box".

If you are persevering enough, you will probably find a solution from someone in this community with your current adapter.

But if you're looking for a quick solution, check at this link :https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported which adapter is compatible (you can find some under 20$) and you will have quickly a working solution !

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation but i think it's a problem with ubuntu. I tried the same with kali and it worked just fine.

Comment: Of course it's an issue with Ubuntu. For example, my Zyxel worked fine on Windows 8. The link I give you is just to have a "out-of-the-box" working adapter with Ubunut ! ;) Good luck on your search !